# Any hints on how to show that this measure $\nu$ is finitely additive but not countably additive.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, intuition

Define the function $\nu: \mathcal M \to [0,\infty]$ by $\nu(A)=\infty$ if $0$ is in the closure of $A$ and $\nu(A) = 0$ otherwise. Prove that $\nu$ is finitely additive but not countably additive.

$\mathcal M$ is the set of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$.

**Any hints on how to show this?**

Comment: @Mark I've edited my post. $\mathcal M$ is the set of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: consider a sequence of measurable sets $A_n$ such that $0 \notin \overline{A_n}$ for any $n$ but such that $0 \in \dots$

Comment: ...but that $0 \in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i = \mathbb R$?

Comment: @AlJebr : the union doesn't need to be the entire real line, but yes, you want $0$ to belong to the (closure) of the union of the $A_n$.

Comment: Ok, so we want $0 \in \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i}$?

Comment: @AlJebr : that's correct. Now you should be able to see why countable additivity fails!

Answer (score 1):

$\nu(\{1/n\})=0$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$ but $0\ne \nu(\{1/n:n\in \mathbb N\}).$

For finite additivity use the fact that $Cl(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^nCl(A_i)$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I think $\nu(\mathbb N)=0$ since $\mathbb N$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ and $0\notin \mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes. And  I didn't type what I was thinking. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

for a fail of countable additivity take any infinite sequence $S$ consisting of distinct points in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and for which $0 \in \bar S$

Comment: Do you mean $0\notin \bar S$?